# Why am I losing fields in my file?

Tags: python

I want to transform input data to CSV to use WEKA for a data mining process. I don't know why I lose some fields in the output of the program. 
I think that the problem is in the second half of the program, when I write the output in the new file, that I am missing some separators, making impossible for WEKA processing the file.

I leave the code and the input file.

PYTHON:

```
#!usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

f = open('datos_terr.csv', 'rb')
fout = open('salida.csv', 'w')
lines = f.readlines()
first = lines[0].strip("\r\n")
fout.write(lines[0] + "\n")
for line in lines[1:]:
    """
    Removing tab characters, used to separate the values. Then I insert NULL values between them for uknown fields. I add "" characters to strings 
    to make WEKA able to accept them, and I put the separation value. I remove the ending tabs and they are subtituted by commas. I write the line
    to the output file and close both.

    Elimino los caracteres de tabulación, que son los que representan la separación. Luego los separo por ellos tras añadir el NULL para
    los campos de los que no conozco los datos. Añado comillas a las cadenas de texto para que WEKA las acepte y añado el caracter de separación.
    Elimino las tabulaciones que me sobren al final y luego los sustituyo por comas. Las escribo al fichero de salida y cierro ambos.
    """
    line = line.strip("\r\n")
    line = line.replace("'", "")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t\t", "\tNULL\tNULL\t")
    line = line.replace("\t\t", "\tNULL\t")
    new_line = ""
    data = line.split("\t")
    for word in data:
        word = word.strip(" ")
        word = word.replace(" ", "")
        if word.isspace():
            word = "NULL"
        if "," in word:
            new_line += '"' + word + '"'
        else:
            if not word.isdigit() and not word == "NULL" and not isinstance(word, float) and not word == "":
                new_line += '"' + word + '"\t'
            else:
                new_line += word + "\t"
    new_line = new_line.strip('\t')
    new_line = new_line.replace("\t", ",")
    fout.write(new_line + "\n")
f.close()
fout.close()
```

The input file can be viewed in this URL:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9PJivXVcFu8c3FLYmFpX0RaVnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Suggestion, use a `RegExp` to replace the characters

Comment: Or just `line.replace("\t","\tNULL")` and remove the last `NULL`

Comment: The problem in your solution, tmoreau, is that I lose the next value if it is not a \t, because I don't have the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `csv` module to get a list of the fields, and work with those. Cleaner code is often easier to find bugs in. You could do the same thing without using the csv module, but that module can already speak several different formats - for example, it will automatically quote fields that have the delimiter in, so you don't need your `if "," in word:` check. You can also check the documentation to see if any of your other checks are handled for you with a simple option: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Your code creates a new string for each line, so I've just created a new list for each line, as an equivalent way of writing the code:

```
with open('datos_terr.csv', 'rb') as incsv, open('salida.csv', 'wb') as outcsv:
    # Read from the first, saying that tab is the field delimiter
    myreader = csv.reader(incsv, delimiter='\t')
    # , is the default, here for explanation
    mywriter = csv.writer(outcsv, delimiter=',')
    for row in myreader:
        # row is a list of the fields.
        newrow = list()
        for field in row:
            # No spaces allowed in fields
            field = field.strip()
            field = field.replace(' ', '')
            # single quotes to be removed, as per original code
            field = field.replace("'", '')
            if len(field) < 1:
                field = 'NULL'
            newrow.append(field)
        mywriter.writerow(newrow)
        # print ', '.join(newrow)
```